# Count Duplicate Data in Column and Display Once Per Row - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table, I'm trying to Count duplicate `Food_Name` into another column called `Duplicate_Value`.

```
SELECT [Food_ID]
      ,[Food_Name]
      ,[Amount]

FROM [Foodie].[dbo].[Food]
```

## Normal Query without Count


[image]

I tried counting Duplicate_Values like this, but when I executed the query it gave me no results

```
SELECT [Food_ID]
  ,[Food_Name]
  ,[Amount]
  ,COUNT(*) as Duplicate_Value
FROM [Foodie].[dbo].[Food]
GROUP BY
   [Food_ID]
  ,[Food_Name]
  ,[Amount]
HAVING 
   COUNT(*) > 1
```

## Desired Output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `COUNT` and `ROW_NUMBER` with windows function to make it.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Food_ID INT,
  Food_Name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'lettuce');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,'lettuce');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3,'lettuce');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,'tomato');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (5,'tomato');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (6,'pick');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (7,'pick');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.[Food_ID]
      ,t1.[Food_Name]
      ,t1.[Amount]
      ,t1.Duplicate_Value 
from(
    SELECT *
      ,COUNT(*) over(partition by Food_Name order by Food_Name) as Duplicate_Value
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Food_Name order by Food_ID) as rn
    FROM [Foodie].[dbo].[Food]
) t1
where t1.rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/608fb/5/0)**:

```
| Food_ID | Food_Name | Duplicate_Value | rn |
|---------|-----------|-----------------|----|
|       1 |   lettuce |               3 |  1 |
|       6 |      pick |               2 |  1 |
|       4 |    tomato |               2 |  1 |
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to get the min(Food_ID) and the count(*) per Food_Name?

Comment: @StevenStip In this case yes.

Comment: @StevenStip can you show me what you mean by min(Food_ID) and the Count(*)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is almost there - the problem is that although the value of `Food_Name` is duplicated, the value of `Food_ID` is not. Since your `GROUP BY` clause includes `Food_ID`, you're going to end up with at least one row for each distinct `Food_ID` value, and since each of those rows only has a count of 1, it gets filtered out in your `HAVING` clause.

Here's a small modification to your solution that should work the way you want it to:

```
SELECT MIN([Food_ID]) AS [Food_ID]
  ,[Food_Name]
  ,[Amount]
  ,COUNT(*) as Duplicate_Value
FROM [Foodie].[dbo].[Food]
GROUP BY
  [Food_Name]
  ,[Amount]
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) > 1
```

Based on your desired output, I wasn't sure what value you wanted for `Food_ID`, so you can try other aggregates than `MIN()`.

If the values in the `Amount` column are also distinct for each row, then you need to remove that column from your `GROUP BY` clause and use an aggregate function in your `SELECT` statement as well:

```
SELECT MIN([Food_ID]) AS [Food_ID]
  ,[Food_Name]
  ,AVG([Amount]) AS [Average_Amount]
  ,COUNT(*) as Duplicate_Value
FROM [Foodie].[dbo].[Food]
GROUP BY
  [Food_Name]
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Hey Shmeeku, this gave me no results when i ran it

Comment: Is the value in the Amount column duplicated? If that value is also distinct for each row, then you'll have to remove that from the GROUP BY as well.

Comment: @taji01, I've edited my answer to include a version that will work with distinct Amount values. Let me know if that works for you!

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation!

```
select min(food_id) as food_id, food_name, count(*) as duplicate_value
from [Foodie].[dbo].[Food] f
group by food_name;
```

Comment: Nice! Simple and Clean but doesn't include amount column is there a reason?

Comment: @taji01 . . . The sample results don't have the amount.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.Food_Name,MIN(t.Food_ID) AS Food_ID,COUNT(t.Food_ID) AS Duplicate_Value
FROM [Food] AS t
GROUP BY t.Food_Name
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.